# Change elements in array mathematica

Tags: arrays, wolfram-mathematica

```
gammaSample = RandomVariate[GammaDistribution[2, 2], 10];
xArray = Array[0, 10];
yArray = Array[0, 10];
Histogram[gammaSample];
PearsonChiSquareTest[gammaSample]
sorted = Sort[gammaSample];
Print[sorted];
For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++; ReplacePart[xArray, i -> (i - 1/2)/100];]
xArray
```

Hello!
I just want to change the values in the Array. I also tried xArray[i]=(i - 1/2)/100 but it doesnt work. How do i do it in mathematica?

Comment: note `ReplacePart` does not modify the array itself, it returns a modified copy.  You need to do something like `array=ReplacePart[array,..]` (though there is likely a better approach to the whole thing )

Answer (score 0):

Array in mathematica is just list, so you should update list, so you should update the 
element in place. Normally, function in mathematica return new object, instead of update
the existing one, like most functional languages, So the following code will not change 
the content of array
    In[5]:= array = {1, 2, 3, 4}

```
Out[5]= {1, 2, 3, 4}

In[6]:= ReplacePart[array, 3 -> 10]

Out[6]= {1, 2, 10, 4}

In[7]:= array

Out[7]= {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

So you can just change the for loop to update in place of the array, and I think there
is a minor error of the For loop, it use comma instead of semicolon to separate the loop
variable and the body of the loop, so the change code is like following:

```
In[24]:= For[i = 1, i <= 10, ++i, xArray[[i]] = (i - 1/2)/100;]

In[25]:= xArray

Out[25]= {1/200, 3/200, 1/40, 7/200, 9/200, 11/200, 13/200, 3/40, \
17/200, 19/200}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although you can do as @user2903066 says, which is to update xArray in place, I suggest that you use Mathematica more like it was meant to be used. It will also make your code easier to read. In this example, you could omit the declaration of xArray and replace the for-loop as follows:

```
xArray = Table[(i - 1/2)/100, {i, 1, 10}]
```